# What is the right pattern for excluding specific file extensions when creating a build step in Jenkins? (Artifacts not to copy)

Tags: jenkins

I'm just starting with Jenkins and trying to set up a Jenkins job which would copy specific files as artifacts (using Copy Artifact Plugin for Jenkins).

However, after the build, it creates extra 8 files with extensions which I don't need as artifacts (.class, .last, .xml).

```
Build Artifacts
App.class   621 B    view
EmptyClass.class    422 B    view
default-compile/createdFiles.lst    87 B     view
default-compile/inputFiles.lst  209 B    view
default-testCompile/createdFiles.lst    44 B     view
default-testCompile/inputFiles.lst  105 B    view
com.github.***.FILE_THAT_I_NEED.txt 541 B    view
TEST-com.github.***.AppTest.xml 6.75 KB  view
AppTest.class
```

Is there a way to specify a pattern which helps to exclude files with extensions which I don't need?

I tried such way:

```
Artifacts to copy   Java/target/***/com.github.FILE_THAT_I_NEED.txt
Artifacts not to copy *.class, *.lst, *.xml
```

But my job still generates those extra files. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the path to the exclusion pattern:

```
Artifacts to copy:   Java/target/**/com.github.FILE_THAT_I_NEED.txt
Artifacts not to copy: Java/target/**/*.class, Java/target/**/*.lst, Java/target/**/*.xml
```

Or, the most simple-rude way, is to delete those files using shell or bat before archiving the artifacts.